# python Printing One result per line

Tags: python, printing

I show below part of a working script to verify twitter accounts that is giving me the results I want one besides the other, while I want to have them one per line including the title of the find

Example, the first three result are for followers, then how many others are being followed, and in how many lists the user is in, and its giving me the results all in one line something like this:

1350 257 27   and I want it to be as follows

Followers:1,350

Following: 257

Number of lists present: 27

I tried to use " ; " commas, "/n " ;   but either it does not work or gives me a 500 Error

Here is the script

All help  will be nice

Thank you

................

```
details = twitter.show_user(screen_name='xxxxxx')


print "content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
print
print"<html><head></head><body>"

print (details['followers_count']) #followers
print (details['friends_count'])# following 
print (details['listed_count'])# In how many lists


...    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the last three print lines, use string formatting to pass in the values.

```
print "Followers:{}\nFollowing: {}\nNumber of lists present: {}".format(
    details['followers_count'], details['friends_count'], details['listed_count']
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, even though I just changed the three last lines as you suggested, I receive a server 500Error

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [print function](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement). You can write multiple arguments in a tab-separated line like:

```
print details['followers_count'], details['friends_count'], details['listed_count']
```

If you want more control over what you print use the `join` function:

```
# Add the parts you want to show
stringParts = []
for part in ['followers_count','friends_count','listed_count']:
    stringParts.append( part + " = " + str(details[part]) )
seperator = ","  # This will give you a comma seperated string
print seperator.join( stringParts )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I erased my last 3 lines of the script and used your first line of instructions and received a Internal Server 500Error

Comment: Then the problem isn't the print statement it's `details`. What is the error you get and where does it occur?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%` operator

```
print 'Followers: %s \nFollowing: %s \nNumber of lists present: %s' % (
    details['followers_count'], details['friends_count'],
    details['listed_count'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, although I deleted my last three lines and used yours I receive a Internal Server 500 Error